# How to sort multiple list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I am trying to sort multiple lists based on the age list from top to bottom. But it always gives me errors.

```
def age(last,name,birthday):
ages=['32','21','35']
names=['Mattie','Meaghan','Gladys']
lasts=['Poquette','Garufi','Rim']
ctr=1
"""I tried the line below but it gives me error! error message: ages,lasts,names = zip(*sorted(zip(ages,lasts,names)))
  ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
   """
 ages,lasts,names = zip(*sorted(zip(ages,lasts,names)))

for bday in birthday:
   my_date = bday
   b_date = datetime.strptime(my_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
   age=("%d" % ((datetime.today() - b_date).days / 365))
   ages.append(age)
for l in last:
   lasts.append(l)
for n in name:
    names.append(n)
# Iwant this to be sorted by age
for a,l,n in zip(ages,lasts,names):
    print(f"{ctr} Employee name {l}, {n} Age:{a}") 
    ctr+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
for i in range(len(ages)): 
    # Find the minimum element in remaining  
    # unsorted array 
    min_idx = i 
    for j in range(i+1, len(ages)): 
        if ages[min_idx] > ages[j]: 
            min_idx = j 

    # Swap the found minimum element with  
    # the first element         
    # and also remining data
    ages[i], ages[min_idx] = ages[min_idx], ages[i] 
    names[i], names[min_idx] = names[min_idx], names[i] 
    lasts[i], lasts[min_idx] = lasts[min_idx], lasts[i] 

# Hence data is sorted by age
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't had problems with this solution

```
ages=['32','21','35']
names=['Mattie','Meaghan','Gladys']
lasts=['Poquette','Garufi','Rim']

ages,lasts,names = zip(*sorted(zip(ages,lasts,names)))
print(ages,lasts,names)
```

Output:

> ('21', '32', '35') ('Garufi', 'Poquette', 'Rim') ('Meaghan', 'Mattie', 'Gladys')

But I recognized, if I save the zip object in a variable at first and then print it out as list  and use this zip object later for sorting, then I get the same Error as you.

```
z = zip(ages,lasts,names)
print(list(z))
ages,lasts,names = zip(*sorted(z))
print(ages,lasts,names)
```

Output:

> [('21', 'Garufi', 'Meaghan'), ('32', 'Poquette', 'Mattie'), ('35', 'Rim', 'Gladys')]
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "c:/Users/*/Desktop/Test.py", line 9, in
>
> ages,lasts,names = zip(*sorted(z))
>
> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)

Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing your data in dictionary like age as key and a list having name and last as element. then you can sort by age easily.

dictionary:
key         Element 
age    ->   [name, last]

Comment: Thank you for the response but I tried to store in the dictionary but it only stores 20% I have 600 students as the data. When I tried this code dictny[a]=l,n  It only stores 20% of the data.

Comment: I think that because your data some duplicate values for age.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of operation, you can also store your data in an array-like structure such as a Pandas [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

```
import pandas as pd
ages=['32','21','35']
names=['Mattie','Meaghan','Gladys']
lasts=['Poquette','Garufi','Rim']
d = {'ages': ages, 'names': names, 'lasts': lasts}
people = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Then `people` would like this DataFrame:

[image: People DataFrame]

And finally, you can use the [`.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) method to sort your data by whatever column you want, e.g. by `lasts` by doing:

```
people.sort_values('lasts')
```

[image: Sorted DataFrame]